# Uso de la barra vertical para dar contexto en noticias

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

En la cafetería de mi edificio tienen puesto el canal 24h de RTVE para *amenizar* los desayunos y almuerzos. En dicho canal la sección inferior de la pantalla está constantemente ocupada por una franja negra donde se suceden los principales titulares del día. Me he fijado en que cuando un titular no es lo suficientemente claro por sí mismo se suele anteponer por un brevísimo texto seguido de una barra vertical. Por ejemplo, hoy aparecía el siguiente titular:

> BRASIL | 305 PERSONAS SIGUEN DESAPARECIDAS

En este caso, el titular sería "305 personas siguen desaparecidas", pero como por sí solo no queda claro de qué trata la noticia, se antepone el texto "Brasil" para dar contexto, y se separan ambas partes del titular con la barra vertical. Esto contrasta con otros casos, como el de los titulares consistentes en citas, que usan el nombre del citado, seguido de dos puntos y la cita entre comillas.

¿Está este uso de la barra vertical recogido en la *Ortografía* de la RAE u otros textos de similar reconocimiento? ¿O debería reemplazarse la barra vertical en estos casos por otro signo de puntuación?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La [*Ortografía* (2010)](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi) detalla su uso en la sección 4.2.4 (p.429). No describe este uso que notas específicamente, pero clarifica que solo lista sus usos *convencionales principales*:

> #### 4.2.4 BARRA VERTICAL O PLECA
>
> La barra vertical (|), también llamada *pleca*, es un signo auxiliar **que actúa fundamentalmente de separador o delimitador** en contextos técnicos, pero que carece de empleo en textos de carácter general.
>
> Este signo aparece siempre precedido y seguido de espacio. Entre **sus principales usos convencionales,** cabe destacar los siguientes:
>
> **a)** en obras sobre versificación clásica, separa los pies métricos que componen los versos, tanto si se reproduce el propio verso como si se representa solo el esquema:
>
> > *El tetrámetro latino responde al esquema:* - ∪ ∪ | - ∪ ∪ | - ∪ ∪ | - ∪.
>
> **b)** En obras de carácter lingüístico, señala la existencia de una pausa breve dentro de un enunciado: *Aquellos que no hayan rellenado el formulario | deberán hacerlo antes de entrar al examen.*
>
> **c)** En matemáticas, se utiliza como signo doble para indicar el valor absoluto de la expresión que encierra: |*ab*|= |*a*|·|*b*|.